# Is conversion function returning an rvalue considered during initializing const lvalue references?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
struct A {
};

struct B{
    operator A() {};
};

int main(){
    B b;
    const A& a = b; // OK
}
```

The rules governing reference initialization can be found in [[dcl.init.ref]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.ref#5):

> A reference to type “`cv1 T1`” is initialized by an expression of type
> “`cv2 T2`” as follows:
>
> - (5.3) Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>
>   - (5.3.1) [..]
>   - (5.3.2) has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be converted to an rvalue or
>     function lvalue of type “`cv3 T3`”, where “`cv1 T1`” is
>     reference-compatible with “`cv3 T3`” (see [over.match.ref]) [..]

I think bullet `(5.3.2)` is applicable here: the initializer expression has class type `B`, and `A` is not reference-related to `B`. Am I correct?

And as far as I understood, `cv3 T3` is the type that the conversion function `B::operator A` yields, which is `A`. Hence, the initializer expression `b` can be converted to an rvalue of type `A` via `B::operator A`, and `cv1 T1` (`const A`) is reference-compatible with `cv3 T3` (`A`). Assuming I correct at this point, I will continue.

Jumping to [[over.match.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.ref):

> Under the conditions specified in `[dcl.init.ref]`, a reference can be
> bound directly to the result of applying a conversion function to an
> initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select the
> conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “reference to `cv1 T`”
> is the type of the reference being initialized, and “`cv S`” is the type
> of the initializer expression, with `S` a class type, the candidate
> functions are selected as follows:
>
> - (1.1) — The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are
>   considered. **Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not
>   hidden within `S` and yield type “lvalue reference to `cv2 T2`” (when
>   initializing an lvalue reference** or an rvalue reference to function)
>   or “cv2 T2” or “rvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an
>   rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function), where “cv1 T” is
>   reference-compatible with “`cv2 T2`”, are candidate functions [..]

I'm initializing an lvalue reference, so only conversion functions that yield an lvalue reference are considered. But the conversion function `B::operator A` yields an rvalue, not an lvalue. So what does this mean? Is `B::operator A` a candidate? Am I misreading any wording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming I am correct at this point, I will continue.

Don't continue. You can't know that the initializer expression is convertible to `cv3 T3` via a conversion function before knowing what `cv3 T3` is. In other words, to check to see if the initializer expression is convertible to `cv3 T3`, you have to invoke [[over.match.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.ref) because `cv3 T3` might not even exist.

So per [[over.match.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.ref), only conversion functions that yields lvalue reference types are considered when you are initializing an lvalue reference. And since your given conversion function returns a non-reference type, the type `cv3 T3` does not even exist; it will exist only if the conversion function returns a reference type. Therefore, [[over.match.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.ref) cannot determine whether or not the given conversion function is a candidate. Hence, [(5.3.2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.ref#5.3.2) failed to apply; therefore, [(5.4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.ref#5.4) is checked.

Comment: Good answer, john.